# Take a sum based upon particular columns

Tags: text-processing, perl

I have a huge pile of data—around 30 to 40 Million data items. We need to process these files and send to another interface team.

Below is my file format which we receive

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
A   B   C   D   5   s
A   B   C   D   4   s
A   B   E   F   5   s
A   B   E   F   8   S
C   D   E   F   9   S
```

I need to print in my output file all of the columns. Since this is related to GPRS usage, we need to group by *c1 - c4* and then if everything is matching we need to sum up the *c5*, and print everything in the output file.

Below is a sample output file.

```
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
A   B   C   D   9   s
A   B   E   F   13  s
C   D   E   F   9   s
```

I also heard that this work flow works a lot faster in Perl than in Unix scripting.

Comment: Why are you printing `s` and not `S` for c6 on `A B E F`?

Comment: Is this one file or many? Do you want a single outfile for all input files?

Comment: Do you need to keep the order of the lines? If so, how is the output order determined (e.g. when you have an `ABCD` line then `ABEF` then another `ABCD`, does `ABCD` end up first or last in the output)? Or are the lines already grouped in the input?

Answer (score 1):

Another `perl` solution, similar to @terdon's answer but with better format output:

```
$ perl -alne '
    (print && next) if $. == 1;   
    $h{"@F[0..3]"}{s} += $F[4];
    $h{"@F[0..3]"}{t}  = $F[5];
    END {
        for (keys %h) {
            printf "%-4s%-4s%-4s%-4s%-4s%-4s",split(" ",$_),$h{$_}{s},$h{$_}{t};                        
            printf "\n";
        }
    }' file
c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6
A   B   E   F   13  S   
A   B   C   D   9   s   
C   D   E   F   9   S
```

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the choice of tools: typically, the more specialized a tool is, the faster it is. So pipes involving `tr`, `cut`, `grep`, `sort`, etc. tend to be faster than `sed` which tends to be faster than `awk` which tends to be faster than `perl`, `python`, `ruby`.  But that of course depends a lot on the task as well. If you read that Perl is faster, then either you misread, or the comparison was against a shell loop that processes one line at a time (that is definitely going to be slow for files with millions of lines).

If your input is in a form where the lines to merge are consecutive, awk is a good bet (there's no sane way to perform additions in sed).

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '                      # use tabs to separate output fields
    NR==1 {print; next}                # keep the first line intact
    function flush () {                # function to print a completed sum
        if (key != "") print previous, sum, more;
        sum=0
    }
    {key = $1 OFS $2 OFS $3 OFS $4}    # break out the comparison key
    key!=previous {flush()}            # if the comparison key has changed, print the accumulated sum
    {previous=key; sum+=$5; more=$6}   # save the current line
    END {flush()}                      # print the last 
'
```

If the lines are not consecutive, you can make them so by sorting. Typical `sort` implementations are highly optimized, and faster than manipulating data structures in high-level languages.

```
sort | awk …
```

This assumes that your column delimiters are consistent, e.g. always a tab. If they aren't, either preprocess the input to make them so, or use `sort -k1,1 -k2,2 -k3,3 -k4,4` to compare these specific fields without taking the delimiters into account.

Answer (score 0):

This could get you started:

```
perl -ane '$h{"@F[0 .. 3]"} += $F[4] }{ print "$_ $h{$_}\n" for keys %h' input-file
```

It doesn't print the last column, as you didn't specify what to do with it. Also, it doesn't handle the header line correctly, but it should be easy to fix.

Comment: @terdon: As mentioned in the reply.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want something like this:

```
$ perl -lane 'if($.>1){$k{"@F[0..3]"}{sum}+=$F[4]; $k{"@F[0..3]"}{last}=$F[5]}
              else{print "@F"}
              END{
                foreach (keys(%k)){ print "$_ $k{$_}{sum} $k{$_}{last}"}
              }' file
c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
C D E F 9 S
A B E F 13 S
A B C D 9 s
```

This will not keep your columns aligned, I don't know if this is an issue for you. It will, however, deal with the header correctly and should produce the output you need.

#### Explanation

- `perl -lane` : The `-l` removes newlines from the end of each string and adds them to each `print` statement. The `a` splits each input line into fields on whitespace and saves the fields in the array `@F`. The `n` means *read the input file line by line and apply the script given by `-e`*.

Here's the same one-liner in commented script form:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

## This is the equivalent of perl -ne
## in the one-liner. It iterates through
## the input file.
while (<>) {
    
    ## This is what the -a flag does
    my @F=split(/\s+/);
    ## $. is the current line number.
    ## This simply tests whether we are on the
    ## first line or not.
    if ($.>1) {
    ## @F[0..3] is an array slice. It holds fields 1 through 4.
    ## The slice is used as a key for the hash %k and the 5th
    ## field is summed to $k{slice}{sum} while the last column is 
    ## saved as $k{slice}{last}.
    $k{"@F[0..3]"}{sum}+=$F[4]; $k{"@F[0..3]"}{last}=$F[5];
    }

    ## If this is the first line, print the fields.
    ## I am using print "@F" instead of a simple print 
    ## so that all lines are formatted in the same way.
    else {
    print "@F\n";
    }
}

## This is the same as the END{} block
## in the one liner. It will be run after
## the whole file has been read.

## For each of the keys of the hash %k
foreach (keys(%k)){ 
    ## Print the key ($_, a special variable in Perl),
    ## the value of $k{$key}{sum} (the summed values),
    ## and the last column.
    print "$_ $k{$_}{sum} $k{$_}{last}\n"
}
```

Comment: In the below command, 

$k{"@F[0..3]"}{sum}+=$F[4]; $k{"@F[0..3]"}{last}=$F[5];

Here in the example file the Keys requreid to be group are in order. If it is not in order then how to use this command.

Please let me know.

Comment: @user2769015 what do you mean? Do you want `ABCD` and `DCBA` to be equivalent?

Comment: My doubt is 
if it is column 1 - 4 continously then the above expression will work.

But if it not in sequnce like i need to check column1 , then column 5 , column 8 and column 12 and sum up the matching in column 16 and print the the output.. 

Can you let me know how to do the hash mapping ?

Also i have one more doubt, IF i am processing data around 10 M what or how much time it will be taking, 
Can this time can be reduced with threads for multiple files ?

Comment: @user2769015 sorry, again, I don't understand what you mean. Please give an example. What do you mean "continuously"?

Comment: Continuously means 

C1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 c10 c11 c12 c13
1  2   3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  13
1  5   3  5  5  8  7  6  9  11  11   x  y

So you need to group according to the columns c1, c3, c5, c7 ,c9  and the matching records in file for the above mentioned columns the colum 11 should be summed up (11+11) and the output should be like this.

c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6
1  3  5  7  9  22

I hope  you will be able to understand this.

Comment: @user2769015 _what_? That has absolutely nothing to do with what you're asking! Please edit your question and show us an example of the format you need to work with. Also, please answer the questions that people have posted in the comments.